# Calculate how much user has scrolled (incl margins & paddings)

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset, scrolltop

I'm stuck with a very annoying problem. I'm trying to create a script that changes the menu bar (CSS) when the user has X pixels scrolled (height of header element). However, any jQuery script I've tried doesn't calculates the scrolled distance correctly. After some pixels it stops counting, and continues.. and then resumes, stops, resumes, etc.

I think it may have something to do with padding and/or margins.. Anyway, I need some support.

Check out [the current site](http://checkspot.nl/appendo/website), with a 'distance scrolled' script appended.

**Script:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(scrollTop);
});
```

Comment: You should animate your transitions to make it more smooth. Current behaviour is absolutely correct. The `scroll` event is emitted as soon as page has been already rendered. Rendering of your page takes a lot of time. Hence lags in scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two scrollbars going for a start. Add `overflow: inherit;` to your body's css to solve this.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9C4wY/)

This should do roughly what you want. At 120px scrolled down, a header slides down overtop the content.

If this doesn't help, please describe exactly what you're trying to achieve a little better.

Comment: Well, that was exactly the problem, indeed! 

Could you perhaps clarify your answer why removing (not adding `inherit`) `overflow-x:hidden;` changes the way the page scrolls? overflow-x is based upon the horizontal Axis, while scrolling is the vertical(y) axis?

Comment: I'm glad! The problem seems to be fixed now, but you had an independent scrollbar for the body inside html which created two scrollbars. I assumed this was an artifact from the parallax template, and it was merely a bit of housekeeping to add the `overflow:inherit;`